# Patent Drawings missing, presents drawing of a another patent? How to get related drawing?

Tags: uspto

In reference to the patent: [US2002098](https://www.google.com/patents/US2002098)

Comment: I looked on the USPTO site and thelens.org and got the same issue. It is a very, very old patent. Is there some interest beyond curiosity?

Comment: You probably have to tell the uspto about the mistake and wait for them to correct it.

Comment: @EricShain Yes! there is an interest rather than just curiosity. This patent got one related feature of my new concept and I need to clear off any anticipation here, so drawing would have been much helpful here.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I will try to contact there and update it here.

Comment: The reply from ptcs@uspto.gov : "Thank you for contacting the Document Services Division. We received your message. We will contact you directly should we have any questions. Requests for certified or uncertified copies of documents may also be placed via the Internet, fax or mail.

Internet Address: http://ebiz1.uspto.gov/oems25p/index.html.
Email address: DSD@uspto.gov
Fax Number: (571) 273-3250 ".